# Getting "parsererror" in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below is my AJAX code. Here I'm hitting a service with one value. The service is getting called successfully, but it is not going into the success method. It is going into the error method only. In the error method it is giving `parsererror` and message: `Unexpected token S`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://domin.com:9000/ramsweb/rest/DetailRest/addOrderContacts/123456/' + customerId,
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#loadingSpinner").hide();
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
        $('.ErrorMsg').html('<h5>An error has occurred</h5>');
    },
    fail: function (data) {
        $('.ErrorMsg').html('<h5>data loading failed</h5>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Probably a problem in the response return, can you add that response to your question?

Comment: What is the value of customerID at the time of your call?  Also, have you tested this web service in isolation?

Comment: add `dataType: "text"` to your ajax.

Comment: @Pamblam — Only if the response is supposed to be plain text (which it, presumably, isn't since the content type is triggering some other kind of parsing).

Comment: @Pamblem - i have added dataType: "text".  now it is working. thanks all

Comment: @Quentin - There are other things besides the Content-Type header that determine how jQuery parses data. In this case looks like jQuery was wrong.

Comment: @Pamblam — Such as? The documentation says it uses the MIME type. It doesn't suggest it ever uses anything else.

Comment: @Quentin - have a look for yourself : http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=_ajaxConvert

Comment: @Pamblam — I can't find anything there (or rather in `function ajaxHandleResponses` which seems more relevant) that doesn't base it off the content-type header.

Comment: keep looking quentin, it;s there... it's guessing the content type if it's not set (which in the case of this question, it's not) and then matching response against other content types..

Answer (score 0):

jQuery AJAX functions by default will try to detect the type of response depending on other pieces of data in your request and response (headers etc.)

Most likely, your endpoint serves it as JSON thus telling jQuery to internally do a `JSON.parse`. However, your endpoint may be serving an error page instead of JSON which can cause parse errors like this.

Comment: Yes, he should specify `dataType`.

Comment: @skobaljic — No, the OP should fix the server side code so it returns data that matches its content-type.

Comment: @skobaljic Not really. Given that the script doesn't tell the type but jQuery still parsing it as JSON, this means the server is telling jQuery the type is JSON even if it's not. That's the root of the problem.

Comment: But maybe he does not want JSON at all.